# Android disable quick launch bar on swipe

Tags: android, swipe, touchscreen

On some devices with Android 6.0.1, when the user swipes from the right screen edge to the left, the quick launch bar is shown.

Is it possible to disable this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

> On some devices with Android 6.0.1, when the user swipes from the right screen edge to the left, the quick launch bar is shown.

That is not part of standard Android.

> Is it possible to disable this programmatically?

Ask the manufacturer of the device that exhibits this behavior.